# Inappbrowserの表示について

Tags: javascript, monaca, html, html5

Inappbrowserを使う際、以下のような実装方法がわかりません。
是非、ご教授頂ければと思います。

・下層面のヘッダー部分を残した表示方法
・表示した後、アプリ側で用意したフッターを表示する方法

アプリ内ブラウザである事をユーザに伝えるには、上記のような工夫が不可欠かと思います。
例えば、リンク集の特定サイトをクリックした際、アプリ内ブラウザで表示する際、アプリ内で表示されている事が認識できませんので・・・。

また、Inappbrowserを使った際、location=yesを使うと、かなり見栄えの悪い＜＞と×が出てしまいます。
これを修正する方法も、ご教示頂けるとたすかります。

出来れば、実例があると助かります。
（どなたかのアプリで実装されていたら、インストールして確認させて頂ければと思います）

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

ご利用されているプランなど、前提条件が分かりませんが2つほど……

`InAppBrowser`はMonacaが採用している**Cordovaプラグイン**です。
Cordovaプラグインが提供しているUIが目的に沿わないのであれば
`WebView`を表示するプラグインを自身で作るか、
sandbox属性を付与してiframe内で表示するかどちらかです。

アプリにもよると思いますが、
iframeであれば難しいことはありません。
ですが、あまり見知らぬWebページを徘徊させるのは危険です。
念のためsandboxを付けるのが無難かと思います。

プラグインを作成する方ですが、
MonacaでやるならGoldプラン以上のアカウントが必要です。
……そもそもプラグインを作成できる能力があるのであれば
素直にCordovaで開発することをお勧めします。

---

**追記**
ちなみに採用しているcordovaプラグインは[こちら](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)になります
Monacaのドキュメントは[こちら](http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/reference/phonegap_3.5/ja/inappbrowser/)です。
どういったWebページを表示するのか分かりませんが
ご自身が管理されているWebページのみを見せるのであれば
ツールバーを非表示にしてしまってWebページでUIを作り
ハッシュやリクエストを付けてURLをアプリ側で読み取りながら制御することも可能です
CordovaはMonacaに比べて更に敷居が高いと思いますし
Cordovaプラグインを作成するとなると`Java`や`Objective-C` or `Swift` or `Swift2`の知識も必要です。
時間と手間暇との相談になるかと思いますが、
何を採用、優先して、どのように実現するかを明確にすると詳しくアドバイスなどを求められるかと思います

Comment: ご回答・ご教示、大変にありがとうございます。
当方、PHPはある程度わかるのですが、MONACAは初めてで、勝手がかなりわかりません。
ともかくCordovaを勉強してみます。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: @kenji 追記しました。CordovaはWebView上でUIを表示しプラグインを通してネイティヴ機能にアクセスします。(MonacaもベースはCordovaです。CordovaにMonaca独自の機能を追加して提供している感じです)HTMLで実現出来ないような事象が出るとプラグインの改造ないし作成が必要になります。